# Account for dynamic top element in React Virtualized `Grid`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a collection of photos that uses React Virtualized's `Grid` element.

[image: photos without tracker]

We've designed an indicator to appear during photo uploads. This hides and shows dynamically and is rendered via the `cellRangeRenderer` per [these docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#cellrangerenderer).

[image: photos with tracker]

The tricky part has been getting the rest of the Grid items to respect the additional height added by this new element. The approach that's currently in place is to add the height of that element to the `style.top` of each element rendered in `cellRenderer`.

```
const adjustedTopOffset = style.top + heightOfTopElement;
```

That above calculation is done for each element. This correctly places all elements at the appropriate offsets. However, the height of the Grid does not adjust for the recalculation of the top offsets.

The consequence is that the bottom of the `Grid` is cut off by the adjusted top amount.

[image: cut off end of grid]

How do I correctly account for adjusted top offsets? Calling `recomputeGridSize` doesn't seem to do it.

Is adjusting the top offset in `cellRenderer` the correct approach for accounting for an additional top element? I'll clarify that this isn't a fixed element but rather one that needs to scroll with the `Grid` like the other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your cell heights are fixed, you should be able to [overrides the default `height` style](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/fb3484ed5dcc41bffae8eab029126c0fb8f7abc0/source/Grid/Grid.js#L1057-L1068) using the `containerStyle` prop, like so:

```
let containerStyle;
if (isTopElementVisible) {
  containerStyle = {
    height: rowHeight * rowCount + heightOfTopElement,
    maxHeight: rowHeight * rowCount + heightOfTopElement,
  };
}
```

Comment: That did it Thank you!